# How to test a hypothesis that customers charged larger fares are more likely to travel alone?

Tags: hypothesis-testing

How to test my hypothesis - the larger the fare the more likely the customer is to be travailing alone?

```
import seaborn as sns

# dataset
df= sns.load_dataset('titanic')
df[['fare','alone']].head()

    fare    alone
0   7.2500  False
1   71.2833 False
2   7.9250  True
3   53.1000 False
4   8.0500  True
```

**Proposed method**

1. Use a paired sample t-test

   - create a large/small fare column
   - split into two datasets on large/small column
   - run the test in python using `stats.ttest_ind`

If there is a more appropriate method, please share.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data is not paired (so a paired test is not appropriate), and the predictor `fare` is continuous, so turning it into a large/small binary throws away useful information.

Instead, this calls for a logistic regression with `fare` as continuous predictor and `alone` as binary response.